# Which subject is more advanced and useful

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, inference

I know this is an open-ended question but I'd like to leverage wisdom of the crowd to make an optimal decision.

The case is, I never learned statistics until 2 years ago. Since then, I'm quite attracted to it and want to solidify my knowledge on the field by looking for some courses to enroll in. I came across these three which sound interesting. The problem is I can only afford to do one of them.

So, if you have to choose, which one would you go for:

1. This course uses *Statistics: The Art and Science of Learning from Data*, 4th Edition 2017
   Alan Agresti, Christine Franklin, Bernhard Klingenberg as texbook. Upon successful completion of this subject students should be able to:

   - Identify and justify statistical concepts and tools to analyse a
     real-world research problem.
   - Use appropriate statistical techniques to conduct exploratory data
     analysis and present numerical and graphical summaries.
   - Apply inferences from sample data to populations.
   - Explain and relate the assumptions underlying the use of
     particular statistical techniques and check whether they are
     appropriate for a given data sample.
   - Conduct statistical analysis and interpret associated computer output.
2. This course uses K.Borovkov, *Elements of stochastic modelling*. and E. Platen, D. Heath, *A benchmark approach to quantitative finance* as textbooks. Upon successful completion of this subject students should be able to:

   - Define and illustrate the terms used in probability and stochastic processes;
   - Discuss and demonstrate the techniques of proof used in probability and some of the mathematical derivations that are important in the theory of stochastic processes;
   - State and apply the basic limit theorems of probability;
   - Demonstrate an ability to use mathematical techniques to analyse the behaviour of various stochastic processes, especially the long-run or steady state behaviour;
   - Formulate and solve applied and theoretical problems involving probability and stochastic processes.
3. This course is called Advanced Bayesian Methods. The subject outline doesn't spell out specific outcomes and no textbook nominated.

Ideally, I want to learn how to learn something practical and useful for my role as safety analyst. I want to be able to use machine learning to model something such as how many accidents will happen given the historical data. Your advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I can safely recommend 1 since I know a lot about Alan Agresti (who is most well-known for his work on categorical data). Bayesian methods are important to know about but I can't recommend 3 because your description is too vague.  I don't know enough to recommend 2 either. I am also not sure how your goals line up with any of these course. You should be more specific about your goals & find courses that are more specific & line up with your goals. This site does not favor questions which are highly opinionated like yours & it could be closed because it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, thank you for your advice. As mentioned in my OP, my goal is to solidify my knowledge in statistics (one of the requirement for Data Science). I know it's very subjective but I like to have more points of views to make an informed decision to choose one out of the three. Also, I don't know where else I could ask this type of questions (I did contact the university offering these courses but very little information could be gleaned from their generic response).

Comment: Can you get in touch with the instructors? Are these three courses your only options. If so why do you have to choose just one? Maybe you could take one now & another later. There could be a natural sequence for taking the courses. But I don't see how anyone can give you good advice without more specific information.

Comment: Nemo, you are comparing three courses that not at all comparable -- they are at very different levels and for very different audiences. Course 1 sounds like an excellent introductory course on statistics from an applied point of view. But if you are have already done 2 years of statistics, have you not already completed an introductory course?? It would be an excellent grounding for you if you have not. (I upvoted Michael Chernick's comment.)

Comment: Courses 2 and (especially) 3 are more advanced and more specialized and don't seem to align with your stated aim to use machine learning. Neither would be appropriate as a first course in statistics. If Course 1 is on your horizon, then you would likely be completely lost in Course 3. You don't say why these courses sounded interesting to you. How can we make a decision for you when it depends so much on your own needs and experience?

Comment: @GordonSmyth, true the 3 courses are at different levels so can't be compared. I've only *known* about Statistics over the last 2 years by taking 2 classes: 1 was generic & the other was Multivariate Statistics (using Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis by Johnson & Wichern as textbook). As I'm only allowed to do 1 more elective, I want to select 1 with most benefits. Probably due to diplomatic reason, no instructor was forthcoming with their replies. Thus, I'd like to see how the public would choose based on their own reasoning so I would go with the majority. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't really. You are asking which Course we would choose, but most people who answer questions on CV are experienced professional statisticians and what we would choose for ourselves might not be appropriate for you. Anyway, if you have completed Multivariate Statistics already, then Course 1 is too elementary for you. Regarding Course 3, ask the Instructor whether you are qualified to take the course after explaining what math and stat courses you have completed so far. The secret is to ask for information, not advice

Comment: @GordonSmyth, thank you so much. Your response is so very helpful: I now know which class I will take. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask "which is more advanced and useful" but we must presume you mean useful to you, not to us. You also say that you can only afford one and that you want to be able to do something "useful". Unfortunately, if we combine those goals with your comments about how much statistics you know (i.e. not much) then they conflict.

One course is not enough.

If I were you, I would take course 1. First, while I don't know that particular text, Agresti is a very good writer. He is a very clear writer, given the level of whatever book or article he is writing. Second, knowing the basics really well is very important (and lacking in many people who call themselves data scientists).

But perhaps I am misreading your statements about how much statistics you know. You mention "hearing about" statistics 2 years ago. But what were you doing for those 2 years? If you were taking statistics courses, then surely one of them covered the sort of material in course 1. But, if that's the case, you would not be asking this question.

Course 2 is going to be much more mathematical. I'd bet that there are mathematical prerequisites for that course. Do you have them?  Were/are you a math major? In any case, I think this sort of theory course is less useful for practical work (other people may disagree).

Course 3 is specialized. Bayesian methods are very popular and useful, but taking course 3 without course 1 (or its equivalent) is like trying to build an apartment building starting on the 10th floor.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for pointing out all the nuances of the three courses. Not only your answer further cements my decision made (as the result of @Gordon's response), it also gives me the idea of how to phrase a subjective question in a more concrete way next time, that is, instead of asking which is an advanced and useful course, I should have explained my current level of exposure to statistics (doing only 2 courses) and what next step (out of the three) I should take.